# Docker container failed because x.cert permission denied

Tags: docker, ssl, grafana

I am trying to add SSL certificate and key to Docker container to use in it. I do not want to use the COPY Dockerfile command, instead, I used the "Bind mount a volume" as follows

```
docker run  -p 443:443 -v grafana-storage:/var/lib/grafana -v /etc/ssl/certs/platform-loc/x.crt:/etc/grafana/x.crt -v /etc/ssl/certs/platform-loc/x.key:/etc/grafana/x.key -e "GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS=yesoreyeram-boomtable-panel"  grafana_app
```

but the previous command failed with the following errors

```
t=2019-08-28T17:33:40+0000 lvl=info msg="HTTP Server Listen" logger=http.server address=0.0.0.0:443 protocol=https subUrl= socket=
t=2019-08-28T17:33:40+0000 lvl=eror msg="Stopped HTTPServer" logger=server reason="open /etc/grafana/x.crt: permission denied"
t=2019-08-28T17:33:40+0000 lvl=info msg="Stopped provisioningServiceImpl" logger=server reason="context canceled"
t=2019-08-28T17:33:40+0000 lvl=eror msg="Server shutdown" logger=server reason="open /etc/grafana/x.crt: permission denied"
```

and this is the content of my Dockerfile

```
FROM grafana/grafana
COPY config /config
USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y vim
RUN cp /config/x.toml /etc/grafana/x.toml &&\
    cp /config/grafana.ini /etc/grafana/grafana.ini
ENTRYPOINT [ "/run.sh" ]
```

Could someone please help me to fix this?

Comment: I think the docker deamon is not able to access the path /etc/ssl/certs/platform-loc/x.crt , try running docker with sudo..

Comment: `root` should have access to the files. Is the server running as another user?

Comment: @SoumenMukherjee  I tried running docker with sudo, it did not solve the issue :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I inspired by Grafana docs to find the answer, basically I had to run

```
chown 472:472 x.*
```

and the problem is solved now

Doc: https://grafana.com/docs/installation/docker/

Comment: cross reference: https://community.grafana.com/t/mount-ssl-certificate-failed-because-of-permission-denied/20597/2

Comment: trying to find something similar for influxdb 2.5 docker, do you happen to know? thanks, M

Answer (score 2):

When the container is launched all files inherit their owner, group and file mask from the host OS.

For that certificate it's probably root:root (or 0:0), readable only by the user. Inside the container the user is grafana (with id 472).

```
> docker run -it --rm --entrypoint bash grafana/grafana
grafana@8edd34dc044d:/usr/share/grafana$ whoami
grafana
grafana@8edd34dc044d:/usr/share/grafana$ grep grafana /etc/passwd
grafana:x:472:472::/home/grafana:/bin/sh
```

So, user grafana can't read the file owned by root.

You could change the permissions on the file to be readable to all, that would solve the problem but at the same time compromise that file on the host.

Or, you could change the user in your image to root but that is considered bad practice.

What solution you choose is up to you. Perhaps this certificate is fine to have world read able.